# Sharepoint 2010 reusable workflow cannot get "Start Date" and reverts to 1/1/0001

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

When trying to apply a reusable workflow on a calendar list to send e.g. an Email containing "Start Time" and "End Time" you will notice that the workflow always reverts this value to 1/1/0001 (the default for a DateTime whereas everything works fine for "End Time".

Setting it up:

[image: AddingStart Time to a workflow Email]

The result:

[image: Before]

Many solutions have been proposed online but do not work, most notably the suggestion to get the "Start Time" indirectly through an indirect lookup:

[image: Indirect lookup]

But the result is very much the same:

[image: After]

This is a major issue in SP2010 if you ask me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a solution however, even if it is not the most elegant.

To circumvent this bug and preserve the flexibility to use reusable workflows as opposed to list specific workflows (where the issue is not present) you have to create a calculated column "Start Time Text" or something similar.

Next apply following formula:

> =TEXT([Start Time],"m/d/yyyy, h:mm:ss AM/PM")

[image: Transform the field to text...]

[image: Update the lookup]

This produces the desired result:

[image]

Thats it. Cumbersome, but it works...